# How to use and pass value to Alias Column of aggregate Function of Date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am using this query to get year from adventureworksLT2008:

```
"select DATEPART(YYYY,SellStartDate) as Year from SalesLT.Product group by DATEPART(YYYY,SellStartDate)"
```

Now I want to just pass year like 1998 and get all the record of 1998

```
"select DATEPART(YYYY,SellStartDate) as 'Years' from SalesLT.Product where Years = '1998'"
```

but I'm getting this error

> Invalid Column Years. SellStartDate datatype is datetime.

Answer (score 1):

`Years` is not defined when the `WHERE` is executed. Have a look at the [execution order](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70efeffe-76b9-4b7e-b4a1-ba53f5d21916/order-of-execution-of-sql-queries?forum=transactsql) of a query.

Use it like this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YYYY, SellStartDate) AS Years
FROM SalesLT.Product
WHERE DATEPART(YYYY, SellStartDate) = 1998
```

Btw the `DATEPART` function returns `int`.

Comment: It works but giving duplicate. But when i try this querySELECT DATEPART(YYYY, SellStartDate) AS Years
FROM SalesLT.Product
WHERE DATEPART(YYYY, SellStartDate) = 1998 and DATEPART(YYYY, SellStartDate)=2002 . It is not showing record between 1998 to 2002

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAVING clause with GROUP BY statements for getting unique values:

```
Select DATEPART(YYYY,SellStartDate) as Year from SalesLT.Product GROUP BY DATEPART(YYYY,SellStartDate)
HAVING DATEPART(YYYY,SellStartDate) = 1998
```

Without a GROUP BY Clause, use [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql)s with full qualifier column names:

```
Select DATEPART(YYYY,SellStartDate) as 'Years' from SalesLT.Product where DATEPART(YYYY,SellStartDate) = 1998
```

You can avoid duplicates just by using DISTINCT

```
Select DISTINCT DATEPART(YYYY,SellStartDate) as 'Years' from SalesLT.Product where DATEPART(YYYY,SellStartDate) > 1998
```